# How to insert extra objects into Rails model list for each_slice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, loops

I'm displaying records in a grid format from an ActiveRecord list using each_slice. What I want to do is randomly insert items into this grid.

My code currently looks something like:

```
<%=things.each_slice(3) do |row|%>
  <div class="row">
    <%row.each do |listing|%>
        <%=show_cell(listing)%>
    <%end%>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

Which produces a grid like so:

```
+----+----+----+
|cell|cell|cell| 
+----+----+----+
|cell|cell|cell| 
+----+----+----+
|cell|cell|cell| 
+----+----+----+
```

What I want to do is have something like

```
+----+----+----+
|cell|cell|cell| 
+----+----+----+
|cell|xxxx|cell| 
+----+----+----+
|cell|cell|xxxx| 
+----+----+----+
```

Where the cells come from the things collection of records, and the xxxx's are randomly inserted (10% chance)

Is there a "ruby" way of doing this without getting rid of the slicing method, and manually keeping a count of when to create new rows?

Comment: Try appending the shuffle method before each_slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new array of mixed Things and Xxxs:

```
mixed_stuff = things.to_a.collect {|t| rand > 0.9 ? t : [t, xxx] }.flatten
```

Then you can do:

<%=mixed_stuff.each_slice(3) do |row|%> etc...

Then in the show_cell(listing) method you can do `if listing.is_a?(Thing)... else listing.is_a?(Xxx)...`

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
>> (1..10).flat_map { |x| rand > 0.1 ? [x] : [x, "xxxx"] }
=> [1, "xxxx", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "xxxx", 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Wish I could answer both this and stef's as right. Unfortunately, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

a cleaner way to handle this is to make an enumerator that randomly serves up 'xxx'. here's my stab at that...

potential problems:

- assumed that sequential xxx's were ok
- what if the total number doesn't divide by 3 any more?

anyways, here it is

```
class Randomizer
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(source)
    @source = source
  end

  def each
    @source.each do |*args|
      while rand < 0.1
        yield 'xxx'
      end
      yield(*args)
    end
    while rand < 0.1
      yield 'xxx'
    end
  end
end

words = %w{foo bar baz bing bang boom}
Randomizer.new(words).each_slice(3) do |row|
  row.each do |word|
    print "#{word} "
  end
  puts ''
end
```

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: THIS DOESN'T WORK randomly hides items, instead of inserting placeholders in between

```
<%= rand>0.9 ? 'xxxxx' : show_cell(listing)%>
```